# bowing down during davening

Tags: tefilla, history, bowing-kneeling

If we look in the [rishonim](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3718), we see that they said that we have to bow when we pray. The gemara (in Meggilah) also said that there are 3 types of bowing during prayer. I'm pretty sure there was also a gemara that said that Rabi Akiva would end up on the other side of the room when he prayed since he bowed all the way down. Then, I think, the [achronim](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3718) said that today we only bow down by bending down while standing – like we do today.

I just want to know why it changed from how we used to bow all the way down to now where we only bend our backs a little while standing.

(I know the gemara in Meggilah said that Abaye and Rava bowed only on their sides, since it said that a tzadik shouldn't bow all the way, but we are not really tzaddikim compared to them. If anyone wants the gemara in Meggilah on this subject, it's daf 22b.) I heard that the Zohar has an answer but we usually don't pasken like the Zohar.

Comment: Yehoshua Nisanov, I've edited your post for readability. I recommend you do it, yourself, in the future, so as to afford a greater opportunity to people to read your question and, concomitantly, to afford yourself a greater chance of getting the answer you seek.

Comment: ok sorry usually i type very fast trying to say all of my sources but i will try to do better next time lol